# Apache Kafka consumer always lagging

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have the following Kafka cluster: 1 zk and 2 brokers,  1zk+1broker on one machine and 2broker on another.
I have the topic with repl-factor=2 partitions=2
I send around 4kmessages into this topic using my producer.
Also, I have a consumer that simply do nothing but consuming records:

```
try {
     consumer.subscribe(topics);
      while (true) {
         ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(0);
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
         }
      }
    } catch (WakeupException e) {
    } finally {
       consumer.close();
    }
```

Consumer has AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG set to 100ms;

So the question is why I always observe the lag between consumer and producer?
I use the following command to get the lag:

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group events-group-test --bootstrap-server kafka01:9092
```

I have cmd script that simply prints lag for me in a loop:

```
-bash-4.2$  while true; do  date +%H:%M:%S;./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group events-group-test --bootstrap-server kafka01:9092 | awk '$5 ~ /[0-9.]+/ { print "part:" $2" lag: "$5}'; sleep 20; done prints 
11:31:04
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

part:0 lag: 1207
part:1 lag: 1100
11:31:29
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

part:0 lag: 5476
part:1 lag: 4692
11:31:53
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

part:0 lag: 3389
part:1 lag: 1646
11:32:16
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

part:0 lag: 1365
part:1 lag: 593
11:32:39
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

part:0 lag: 4575
part:1 lag: 3488
11:33:03
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
```

As you see it always shows the lag ~3-4k messages but my consumer literally does nothing with the records, so it should consume instantly and I expect the 0 lag.
Also, I've tried to decrease producer load to 30 messages per sec, but the consumer still shows the LAG (~30-50). Is it possible to reach 0 LAG?

Comment: Is the producer running in the background? The consumer **is** doing something... `part:0 lag: 5476` ... `part:0 lag: 3389` ... `part:0 lag: 1365` ... What are you looking at? Maybe you should set `poll(0)` to a higher number to get more records?

Comment: yeah, the producer sends messages even from another env.
My consumer literally does nothing with the records, so it should consume instantly and I expect the 0 lag. I tried to set a poll timeout to LONG.MAX_VALUE but it doesn't help

Comment: Well, just because you're doing nothing with the records doesn't mean the poll loop itself will be faster. If you literally want to do nothing, then you should use the seek to end methods... If you're doing this for testing IO rates, Kafka already includes performance tools for production and consumption